# Restoring a Elasticsearch spapshot from Windows to Debian

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm trying to restore a snapshot I created in a computer, but I need to restore it into another. I successfully created a repo and a first snapshot, I assume it because have results from these queries:

```
GET /_snapshot/_all
GET /_snapshot/my_repo_1/snapshot_1
```

My elasticsearch instance is configured to save the snapshoots in:

```
path.repo: D:\BACKUP
```

So I copied the full folder (with a dir called "my_repo_1" and another 5 files), and I moved it into another computer with a clean instance of elasticsearch (under other operating System). I configured the elasticsearch.yml file to match the location of the copied file:

```
path.repo: /home/BACKUP
```

And I restarted the service, but when running:

```
curl 'localhost:9200/_snapshot/_all'
```

I got an empty response.
Any idea why it isn't working'?

Comment: I think you missed some extra required steps. Docs here helped me do the same operation: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/cloud/current/ec-migrate-data.html So in essence you need to create a repository from the existing snapshot.

Comment: Yep, you're right! Thanks!